# How do I tell jQuery to not bubble up the tree when using contains(string)?

Tags: jquery, contains

I need to hide a div that has a certain string in it, using contains.. but jQuery is hiding all div's that are parents of the target div too !

```
 $("div:contains('user_notifications')").css("display","none")
```

how do I tell jQuery to just match the div that actually contains that string?

Thanks

---

Edit:

here's the inner div that contains the string I want to match..

```
<div class="group" style="display: block;">

 <input type="hidden" value="0" name="user[notification_options[new_reply]]" style="display: block;">

 <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="user[notification_options[new_reply]]" id="user_notification_options[new_reply]" checked="checked" style="display: block;">

 Request help from system admin

 </div>
```

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Comment: pretty bad!  ...and I can't touch it..  it's just a bunch of div's with no class or ID attributes

Comment: Can you post just the innermost div? e.g. does it have a div inside it, beside this text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the div doesn't have divs that are siblings to the text, you can do this:

```
$("div:contains('user_notifications'):not(:has(div))").hide();
```

This uses [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) to get the opposite of [`:has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) to only select `<div>` elements that don't contain other `<div>` elements, eliminating the parents.  Also I'm using [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) here as a simpler `display: none;`, in case you want to show it later.

Comment: Nick - Thanks for the correction on my answer (deleted). +1 :o)

Comment: I included the html above.. but I think this works.. thanks much!

Comment: @Joseph - Let me know if it doesn't....I don't see the `user_notifications` string in the posted HTML, you may need a slightly different selector, something like this: `$("div:has(input[name*='user[notification_options']):not(:has(div))")`.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your HTML, this would be more suitable:

```
$("input[name*=notification_options]").parent("div").hide();
```